# How do I count the number of commands a user ran?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a table that looks like this

```
user_id   ...
1         ...
1         ...
2         ...
```

And I would like a table that looks like this

```
user_id   num_commands   ...
1         2              ...
2         1              ...
```

I'm using the query

```
select
user_id as id,
count(user_id) as num_commands,
...
from table_name
group by user_id
```

But it's returning the error `FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 4:0 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'num_commands'`. This seems nonsensical to me; I realize that num_commands isn't in the GROUP BY statement, but it's the result of an aggregating function, so why does it matter?

Comment: if you select more columns you must set these column in group  by ..you can't perform a "partial " group by

Comment: Unless I'm using an aggregating function, no? Like I can do `select x, avg(y) from table group by x`, can't I?

Comment: If I'm misunderstanding, could you link me to a resource that would better explain this?

Comment: I have posted an asnwer  hope is useful

Comment: Yuo have used count(user_id) and group by user_id  this raise the SemanticException .. you should use count(*)  like  suggested in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is wrong

```
select
 user_id as id,
 count(user_id) as num_commands
 from table_name
 group by user_id
```

count(user_id) and group by user_id raise the Exception

```
select
 user_id as id,
 count(user_id) as num_commands,
 other_column1, 
 other_column2 
 from table_name
 group by user_id
```

this is wrong because not the column in group by

this is right

```
select
 user_id as id,
 count(*) as num_commands,
 other_column1, 
 other_column2 
 from table_name
 group by user_id, other_column1,      other_column2 


select
 user_id as id,
 count(*) as num_commands,
 sum(other_column1), 
 avg(other_column2) 
 from table_name
 group by user_id
```

Comment: update your question and show me the exact code you are using .. please ..

Comment: My mistake, I re-ran the old code instead of the updated code. Thanks!